# How to implement fixed layout ePubs in iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, layout, fixed, epub, ibooks

I am trying to develop an application which can support fixed layout ePub formatted books with some images also (like children's books). I have successfully implemented the ability to open other kinds of books like simple ePub books by using **[AnFengDe's SDK](https://github.com/AnFengDe/EPUB_SDK)**. It's all working great except some problems like chapter listings.

I have a problem with opening fixed layout books. You can test this kind of book by opening them in the SDK's UI. I want my application to also support [this kind of book](http://www.epubbud.com/book.php?g=LYN6T7SC). This book opens perfectly in iBooks, but in AnFengDe's SDK it's not going to be used and opened perfectly.

I do not understand how to differentiate books that are fixed layout or simple books.
Can anybody give me some suggestions and reference source code?